# Gallio integration with Nant and Hudson

Tags: testing, build, hudson, nant, gallio

Here is the situation, I am attempting to fire a set of Gallio tests after the build/deploy process to a server. The build script is Nant and we activate it via Hudson to the remote servers.

After a good bit of effort I have ran into the following error from our build script.
NOTE: I scrubbed the file paths and replaced them with (Description)

```
Buildfile: file:///(Build script location)
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0
Target(s) specified: build-robot 


[include] Including file (Build script location)
[property] Read-only property "doDeploy" cannot be overwritten.
[property] Read-only property "runSmokeTests" cannot be overwritten.
[tstamp] Tuesday, November 22, 2011 3:51:01 PM.
[tstamp] Tuesday, November 22, 2011 3:51:01 PM.
[echo] Setting RELEASE mode to true
[echo] The Output Folder is set to: (Nightly build server)
[echo] Loading Gallio Task from: (Source dir path)\References\Gallio\Gallio.NAntTasks.dll
[loadtasks] Scanning assembly "Gallio.NAntTasks" for extensions.

global.failure:


tear.down:

 [echo] In tear.down...

clean:

 [echo] Starting clean target...
 [echo] End of clean target...

BUILD FAILED - 0 non-fatal error(s), 2 warning(s)

(output dir)(30,3):
Failure scanning
"(Source dir path)\References\Gallio\Gallio.NAntTasks.dll" for extensions.
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

Here is the script area where I load the assembly.

```
<!-- Load Gallio Tasks for automated Testing -->
<echo message="Loading Gallio Task from: ${path::combine(repoDirectory,'Source\References\Gallio\Gallio.NAntTasks.dll')}" />
<loadtasks assembly="${path::combine(repoDirectory,'Source\References\Gallio\Gallio.NAntTasks.dll')}"  if="${file::exists(path::combine(repoDirectory,'Source\References\Gallio\Gallio.NAntTasks.dll'))}"  /> 
<echo message="Failed to find Gallio.NantTasks.dll" unless="${file::exists(path::combine(repoDirectory,'Source\References\Gallio\Gallio.NAntTasks.dll'))}"  /> 
<echo message="${LoaderExceptions}" />
<echo message="Gallio Tasks Loaded..." />
```

And the Gallio task itself.

```
<target name="run.automated.tests"> 
    <echo message="Begining Automated Testing..." />
    <property name="nant.onfailure" value="global.failure" />       

    <gallio result-property="exitCode" failonerror="false" >

        <files>
            <include name="${path::combine(outputDirectory,'bin\AutomatedQATest.dll')}" />
        </files>
        <!--
        <runner-extension value="AutomatedQATest,Gallio.AutomatedQATest" /> 
        <assemblies>                
          <include value="${path::combine(outputDirectory,'bin\AutomatedQATest.dll')}" /> 
        </assemblies>  -->
    </gallio>
    <fail message="Oh no!" if="${exitCode} != '0'}" />
</target>
```

Any ideas? I have spent the better part of today searching for an answer, Google either presents me with depreciated work arounds or ideas that don't work.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What version of Gallio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come to find out this is several problems acting together. First off the tasks were not loaded correctly: Gallio requires the Gallio.dll AND Gallio.Nant.tasks.dll to be loaded.

Secondly the tests I was attempting to run required a gui to run properly, in order to have 
 a gui on a remote machine you have to set an interactive flag. Gallio does not have a flag for this, so I ended up dancing around that issue by calling PSEXEC.exe to run Gallio.Echo.exe on the remote machine with interactive mode on and set to use RDP-TCP session id #1. The command in nant looks like this.

```
<exec program="psexec.exe" failonerror="false" >
    <arg line="\\${test.auto1.serverpath} /accepteula -i 0 -u ${DevUsername} -p ${DevPassword} C:\Gallio\bin\Gallio.Echo.exe (The path) ${build.version}.${date.prefix}\bin\${theTargetTest} /rd:C:\Reports /rt:HTML /ra:zip /rnf:${projectName}-${date.cal}" />
</exec>
```

So basically in the end I removed the need to have nant run the tests by having it call Gallio with the correct parameters on the remote machine directly with the above command after I build, zip the required bits up, move it to the server and unzip it. After the test finishes I zip up the test report and move it back to the hudson server.

Hope this saves someone some pain in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Fusion logging to get more detailed error messages.

See this tutorial:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

I'm thinking there is one or more missing dependencies.